# Basic Row Traversal Question

Tags: matrix

Right now I'm using this `For` loop to do an operation to each row of a $n \times n$ matrix, I was trying to figure out how to do this with `Map` or `Take` or something like that.

```
evecs = RandomReal[1, {5, 5}]
For[{i, 1, Length@evecs}, i++, evecs[[i, All]] = evecs[[i, All]]/Norm[evecs[[i, All]]]];
```

Comment: Code doesn't run as-is. `For[i=1,Length@evecs,i++...`

Comment: @CoreyKelly yes youre right, haha what is wrong?

Comment: Is this what you want ?
`evecs2 = #/Norm[#] & /@ evecs`

Comment: @Emy oh that was silly, /@ already takes the rows it doesnt map to each element of the array, i think that is where i got confused. Thanks that is it, but i still wonder why the for loop doesnt work?

Comment: `Normalize /@ evecs`

Comment: @CoreyKelly hah, even easier!

Comment: I wrote what was wrong with the `For` loop in my first comment. Look closely.

Comment: Can I put my comment as an answer then? I've never had an accepted answer :)

Comment: @CoreyKelly, on for loop: OHHHH haha Duuh! thanks.   Normalize/@evecs doesnt works like a charm, i can accept that as an answer :) thanks Emy & Corey. (Sorry Emy, Corey got back to me first and i used his, i can still upvote yours though)

Comment: Go ahead. Add my suggestion as a concise alternative.

Comment: @CoreyKelly  is that for me or Emy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the basic approach of applying a function to the first level in a list (i.e. the 'rows' in a matrix) you have :

`#/Norm[#] & /@ evecs`

As CoreyKelly pointed out though, in your case you are just normalizing the elements, so you can apply the `Normalize` function :

`Normalize /@ evecs`

Comment: congrats on your first answer Emy!!

Comment: Thanks mate. And thanks to Corey for letting me have it. :)